# Can't set properties for logo image to be responsive

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I want to build a navbar that's changing his size when scrolling down. The problem is that I don't know how to make my logo image to be responsive. I mean when the header is on the top to be full width and height, and when I make my nav smaller to be scaling down.

Down here I have just a simple code from code pen to show you what I'm trying to get

```css
nav {
  background: #555;
  height: 80px;
}

.nav-content {
  display: flex;
}

.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <div>
      <img class="logo" src="http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/logo1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>Number1</li>
      <li>Number2</li>
      <li>Number3</li>
      <li>Number4</li>
      <li>Number5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you miss adding the logo in your example

Comment: anyway you have to add a bit of JS, to understand when the page scrolls, and from there modify your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this styling for the li tag and will give you responsive header bar and I hope this is what you are looking for

```
ul li {
  padding: 1vw 4vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to the image every time you want to be responsive

Comment: How can this be an acceptable answer unaccepting the right one @DConstantin

Comment: didn't see that, I'm sorry about the issue, I wanted to give that answer a 'useful' hit not to make it the top answer.